# How to change image source attribute through directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following image tag:

```
<img src="default.png" data-new-image/>
```

`newImage` is a directive that I have defined that will fetch the image from the server (based on some criteria) and while it calculates and fetches the image, I have the default.png image file shown.

In this directive, I have defined the `link` function as:

```
return {
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        //My custom logic here to determine which image to show
        //and then fetch from the server
        //After HTTP request, assigning image to image source
        attrs.src = "image_fetched_from_server.png";
    }
};
```

But this does not update the images src attribute. I can see the image fetched clearly and a `console.log(attrs)` after assigning the image shows that the source attribute was updated with new image. But the DOM inspector in the browser shows no change to the source - it still shows default.png

I am using directive here and not controller - I understand I can use controller and use `ng-src` but I have this logic across multiple controllers and a directive is the best option I have. How do I change the source of the image tag? I wonder how `ng-src` does it?

Comment: "I wonder how ng-src does it?" => you know that angularjs is open source ? You should really use ngSrc

Comment: @Bixi :) I know that. I went through it but could not understand it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the cause.

To set values in the attribute, I needed to use `attrs.$set(attribute_name, value)`.

Thus, I replaced `attrs.src` with `attrs.$set('src', 'image_fetched_from_server.png');` and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

ng-src is nothing but another directive which passes a "source" attribute (or binds it) to a given directive / whatever.

So - what is the name of the directive you are trying to make? One option might be to encompass the entire `<img.../>` tag in your `image-loader-directive`

The other issue that might be occurring, could have to do with the fact that your DOM defines `src="default.png"` instead of something like `src="{{ image_src }}"`. This way the minute your directive decides to change the meaning of image_src - the DOM will refresh and hence pull the correct image from its source.